# Law of Total Probability: does not match with complement rule (playing cards: probability second card is red)

Tags: probability

Suppose I draw two cards, without replacement, one at a time, from a well-shuffled deck.

I want to know the probability that the second card is red.

Let A = "1st card is red"

Let B = "2nd card is red"

So I want to know P(B).

Since the probability that the second card is red depends on whether or not the first card was red, I can express this using the Law of Total Probability:

P(B) = P(B|A)P(A) + P(B | Abar)P(Abar)
= (25/51)(26/52) + (26/51)(26/52)

which is approximately equal to 0.4902.

I understand that much, but then P(Bbar) should be approx. 1 - 0.4902 = 0.5098

But if I use the Law of Total Probability here, then I get:

P(Bbar) = P(Bbar | A)P(A) + P(Bbar | Abar)P(Abar)

= (26/51)(26/52) + (25/51)(26/52)
= 0.5

Why are these numbers so different? Shouldn't I have gotten exactly 0.5 for P(B)?

Comment: Your expression for $P(B)$ is identical to your expression for $P(A).$

Comment: how did you get .4902? (25/51)*(1/2)+(26/51)*(1/2) = (1/2)*(25/51+26/51) = (51/51)*1/2 = 0.5

Comment: Thank you @Ryan! I plugged it in three or four times, got 0.4902. I plugged it in again and got 0.5. Whew!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking the question about the second card before you look at the first card. Whether any given card in a shuffled deck is red, without any other knowledge about any of the cards, is 50%.

Also, you are giving two different answers for the same calculation. 
(25/51)(26/52) + (26/51)(26/52) = (26/51)(26/52) + (25/51)(26/52)
... and that equals 0.50.

In any event, the probability that a red card is the first card on a deck with 51 cards, having 25 red cards and 26 black cards is 25/51 = 0.4901961